# How to show android built in battery usage inside my own app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, battery

I'm currently showing the android built in battery usage with an Intent like this:

```
Intent powerUsageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY);
```

This approach launches a whole new Activity and works fine, but I need to show that very information inside my own application - on a fragment in my own UI

Can someone tell me how to pull the "raw data" from the system?